# GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received. error after removing all files in public_html

Tags: debian, ftp

Connecting to my FTP worked perfect the past months until I deleted all files in the **public_html** directory which is also the directory root of this FTP account. I deleted all files using:

> rm -rf *

while I was in the public_html folder. All folders are still intact, I also added index.php check if the server is still running.

Complete log:

> Status:   Connecting to {server_ip}...
>  Status:    Connection
>   established, waiting for welcome message...
>  Status:   Initializing
>   TLS...
>  Status:    Verifying certificate...
>  Status:    TLS connection
>   established.
>  Command: USER {username}
>  Response:   331 Please
>   specify the password.
>  Command:    PASS ********
>  Error:    GnuTLS
>   error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
>  Error:  Could not
>   connect to server
>  Status: Waiting to retry...
>   Status:   Connecting to {server_ip}...
>  Status:    Connection
>   established, waiting for welcome message...
>  Response: 220 (vsFTPd
>   3.0.2)
>  Command:   AUTH TLS
>  Response:  234 Proceed with negotiation.
>  Status:   Initializing TLS...
>  Status: Verifying
>   certificate...
>  Status:    TLS connection established.
>   Command:  USER {username}
>  Response:   331 Please specify the
>   password.
>  Command:    PASS ********
>  Error:    GnuTLS error -15: An
>   unexpected TLS packet was received.
>  Error:    Could not connect to
>   server

Comment: This is the client log.  What does the server log say?

Comment: Mon Mar  6 23:58:50 2017 [pid 16629] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:12.34.567.89"
Mon Mar  6 23:58:50 2017 [pid 16628] [username] OK LOGIN: Client "::ffff:12.34.567.89"

Answer (score 2):

I just added this to my vsftpd.conf

> allow_writeable_chroot=YES

And then restarted vsftpd using:

> service vsftpd restart